# Error message while downloading excel file from web portal using ssis Script Task

Tags: ssis, webclient, script-task

I am wondering if someone can help me with something. I created an SSIS package (using script task) to download a file from Web portal and then process it. However, package worked fine for few months but started failing over last 2 days. I am getting a strange error message. However when i copy and paste this web portal url to Chrome, file gets downloaded perfectly fine. No idea what's causing this failure in automation. (Attached)[image]

Comment: Add some more details like script task code  and check is any spacial character or space in file name.

Comment: The error message doesn't look strange, infact it says two files are missing. Have you verified them.

Comment: Hi @Abhishek Many thanks for your reply. yes, files does exist. When i manually paste the url in chrome/IE, it asks for username and Password. After entering the credentials, it downloads the file for me. As i have explained above, process was working perfectly fine until couple of days back when i started getting the error message.